# South African Mobile number formatting

Tags: php, regex, mobile

I'm still trying to get my head around the preg_replace function in PHP. How do I format the following mobile numbers into a standard 27xxxxxxxxx for mobile numbers?

Eg:

083-123-4678  should be 27831234567
+278312345678 should be 27831234567

The starting numbers all must be either 081, 082, 083, 084 or 071, 072, 073, 074

Comment: >>081, 082, 083, 084 or 071, 072, 073, 074 
Assuming only starting with *[7|8][1|2|3|4] is a silly idea because with ATA you are going to have new numbers. Also there is 078 that you aren't catering for.

Answer (score 2):

```
    function Number_SA($numbers)
{
$number = preg_replace(array('~[^0-9]~', '~^27~'), '', $numbers);

    if (preg_match('~^(?:07[1234])~', $number) > 0)
    {
        $output= sprintf('%d%s', 27, $number);if ((strlen($output) < 12)| (strlen($output) > 13)){ return false;}
         else{return $output;}

    }
    elseif (preg_match('~^(?:08[123458])~', $number) > 0)
    {
        $output= sprintf('%d%s', 27, $number);if ((strlen($output) < 12)| (strlen($output) > 13)){ return false;}
         else{return $output;}

    }
    elseif (preg_match('~^(?:01[123468])~', $number) > 0)
    {
        $output= sprintf('%d%s', 27, $number);
        if ((strlen($output) < 12)| (strlen($output) > 13)){ return false;}
         else{return $output;}

    }
    elseif (preg_match('~^(?:02[1])~', $number) > 0)
    {
        $output= sprintf('%d%s', 27, $number);

         if ((strlen($output) < 12)| (strlen($output) > 13)){ return false;}
         else{return $output;}

    }       
    elseif (preg_match('~^(?:03[1])~', $number) > 0)
    {
        $output= sprintf('%d%s', 27, $number);
        if ((strlen($output) < 12)| (strlen($output) > 13)){ return false;}
         else{return $output;}

    }  
    elseif (preg_match('~^(?:04[0134])~', $number) > 0)
    {
        $output= sprintf('%d%s', 27, $number);
        if ((strlen($output) < 12)| (strlen($output) > 13)){ return false;}
         else{return $output;}

    }  
    elseif (preg_match('~^(?:05[17])~', $number) > 0)
    {
        $output= sprintf('%d%s', 27, $number);
        if ((strlen($output) < 12)| (strlen($output) > 13)){ return false;}
        else{return $output;}

    }  
    else{return false;}

return false;
}


$phoneno=array();
array_push($phoneno,(Number_SA('083-313-2605'))); //true
array_push($phoneno,(Number_SA('067-313-26055')));//false
array_push($phoneno,(Number_SA('021-313-260'))); //false
array_push($phoneno,(Number_SA('0211-313-8903')));//true



foreach ($phoneno as $number){
if($number == ""){ echo "Phone Number is null"."<br/>";}
else{ echo "This is valid: ".$number."<br/>";}}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
function Number_SA($number)
{
    $number = preg_replace(array('~[^0-9]~', '~^27~'), '', $number);

    if (preg_match('~^(?:07[1234]|08[1234])~', $number) > 0)
    {
        return sprintf('%d%s', 27, $number);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Usage:

```
var_dump(Number_SA('083-123-4678'));    // 27831234567
var_dump(Number_SA('085-123-4678'));    // false
var_dump(Number_SA('+278312345678'));   // false (doesn't start with 083)
```